# Call data from SQLite Database

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

So I need anyone to help me to scan the problem inside my codes. The page crash every time i try to run it. I think the problem occurred due to the following codes.

DBController.java

```
public ArrayList<ProfileDB> getResult(String profileDOB, String profileSex,
        String profileWeight, String profileHeight, String textWorkout,
        String textLevel, String textWorkWeight, String textResult) {

    ArrayList<ProfileDB> profileList = new ArrayList<ProfileDB>();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_DOB, KEY_SEX, KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_HEIGHT,
            KEY_WORKOUT, KEY_LEVEL, KEY_WORKWEIGHT, KEY_RESULT }, KEY_DOB
            + "='" + profileDOB + KEY_SEX + "='" + profileSex + KEY_WEIGHT
            + "='" + profileWeight + KEY_HEIGHT + "='" + profileHeight
            + KEY_WORKOUT + "='" + textWorkout + KEY_LEVEL + "='"
            + textLevel + KEY_WORKWEIGHT + "='" + textWorkWeight + "' and "
            + KEY_RESULT + "='" + textResult + "'", null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            ProfileDB p = new ProfileDB(cursor.getInt(0),
                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4),
                    cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6),
                    cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8),
                    cursor.getString(9));

            profileList.add(p);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return profileList;

}
```

Continue.java

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    parent.getId();
    ArrayList<ProfileDB> profileList = database.getResult(null, null, null,
            null, null, null, null, textResult.getText().toString());

    String str = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < profileList.size(); i++) {
        str += profileList.get(i).getTextResult() + "\n";
    }
    textResult.setText(str);
```

This is the error I get from the LogCat.

```
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/SQLiteLog(32596): (1) near "nullprofileWeight": syntax error
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596): Process: com.etty.theiglove2, PID: 32596
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "nullprofileWeight": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT profileId, profileName, profileDOB, profileSex, profileWeight, profileHeight, textWorkout, textLevel, textWorkWeight, textResult FROM profiles WHERE profileDOB='nullprofileSex='nullprofileWeight='nullprofileHeight='nulltextWorkout='nulltextLevel='nulltextWorkWeight='null' and textResult='100
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1121)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:694)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1436)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1283)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1154)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1322)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at com.etty.theiglove2.DBController.getResult(DBController.java:177)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at com.etty.theiglove2.Continue.onItemSelected(Continue.java:82)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:956)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.widget.AdapterView.access$200(AdapterView.java:49)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:920)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
05-08 00:34:55.072: E/AndroidRuntime(32596):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Hope somebody could help me to find the problems. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `selection` parameter of your `query` call, besides being formatted so that it's unreadable, is nowhere near valid SQL; individual comparison expressions must be combined with `AND`.
Furthermore, putting string values directly into the SQL string will blow up when any of them contains quotes; use parameters instead:

```java
Cursor cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME,
    new String[] { KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_DOB, KEY_SEX,
                   KEY_WEIGHT, KEY_HEIGHT, KEY_WORKOUT,
                   KEY_LEVEL, KEY_WORKWEIGHT, KEY_RESULT },
    KEY_DOB        + "= ? AND " +
    KEY_SEX        + "= ? AND " +
    KEY_WEIGHT     + "= ? AND " +
    KEY_HEIGHT     + "= ? AND " +
    KEY_WORKOUT    + "= ? AND " +
    KEY_LEVEL      + "= ? AND " +
    KEY_WORKWEIGHT + "= ? AND " +
    KEY_RESULT     + "= ?",
    new String[] { profileDOB, profileSex, profileWeight, profileHeight,
                   textWorkout, textLevel, textWorkWeight, textResult },
    null, null, null);
```

Comment: Hi @CL. Based on many examples, yours are one of the method that I have used before. But unluckily it was not working. And I've tried again just now (hope for luck) but the result is still the same. Using your method, this error was what I get. 05-08 14:53:16.432: E/AndroidRuntime(24593): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 7 is null. Hope you may help.

Comment: The problem in your question is solved; this is a different question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. My program is still crash when I try to run this, even by using your codes.

Comment: This crash is caused by another bug in your app.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you don't have spaces between your column names and your values. Try like this:

```
KEY_DOB + "='" + profileDOB + " " + KEY_SEX + "='" + profileSex + " " + ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt help! I have tried your method but unsuccessful. Is there any other way?